# Get Analyse Form Result API is returning error code 3003

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, error-code, azure-form-recognizer

I used the form labelling tool to train my model. I have got the modelID, run the Analyse Form API successfully, but when called the get analyse form result, I've got the error code:

3003 "OCR extraction error: [Wrong response code: FailedToDownloadImage. Message: Failed to download image from input URL..]"

I haven't tested the model on any of these 5 pictures that I used for training purposes. Instead, I used 3 completely new documents.

Any idea how I could get this to work? 
[image]

This is the form I analysed (pdf) [image]

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the 3 new documents to analyze, do you submit them from your Azure storage blob, or local file system,  or from other places with a URL?  if it's the last case (URL),  the current service has a bug.   You could try the first 2 options, and see if they solve your problem.

-xin (Form Recognizer Team)

Comment: Option 1: I placed the documents for analysis to Azure storage blob and it doesn't work. I tried two options: a) to use another blob on the same storage account that I used to place documents for training - didn't work and got the error message that i shared above; b) to use the same blob storage account that I used to place the documents for training purposes - didn't work. So, with 99% of confidence, I can confirm that the model that the labelling tool creates can't be used as a part of request for API call.(1/2)

Comment: (2/2) more precisely - the issue is in the get result call.

Comment: when you said:  _Option 1: I placed the documents for analysis to Azure storage blob and it doesn't work._ what's the error message?

Comment: 3003 "OCR extraction error: [Wrong response code: FailedToDownloadImage. Message: Failed to download image from input URL..]"

Comment: my assets (form recognizer) and storage account are deployed in the west Europe region (v 2.0)

Comment: I can report the similar issue. I tried all 3 variations with different files, sizes, headers and methods. And e.g. if I do not make any changes to my code and continue to request ill get  "notStarted" status and "failed" status randomly. And the error code when it's failed is ( code: "3003"
message: "OCR extraction error: [Wrong response code: InvalidImageSize. Message: The input image is too large. It should not be larger than 20MB..]" )

Answer (score 0):

Check your url for encoding standards.
This error can be throwed when you send an url without url encoding. 
For example spaces need to be rapleced by %20.
Indeed this url:

```
"https://test.com/Attachments/Recognized 3728_001.pdf"
```

needs to be changed to

```
"https://test.com/Attachments/Recognized%203728_001.pdf"
```

Check [this link](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) for other cases: